# Imitate "text to column" in excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have a SQL table that I'm exporting to Excel, the table has a column with "Date" format, but when the information moves to Excel it doesn't recognize it, I get the values this way.

[image]

But I need them in date format, this way

[image]

For filtering, I've tried different convert options but I'm still getting the same result

I've tried convert to date, to varchar, etc

Comment: how are you "exporting" the table?  If you do not want to use Text-To-Columns to convert the text to a date, you will need to start at the source or adjust the method of import.

Comment: From the connections section at excel, and the table in sql has date format

Comment: Then when you set up the connection to that table choose transform and make sure that column is set to date/time. then load.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: "I've tried a bunch of different ways" - you need to show us what you've tried - maybe you made a mistake with the way you did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try pulling in data from within Excel using Get Data -> From Database -> From SQL Server Database, the dates are imported as Excel dates, not the strings that you're seeing.  Excel should be converting those for you automatically.

If you're using something like SQL Server Mgt Studio and copying and pasting the results, you *will* get strings like you're seeing.  In that case, you can format the dates in your query using the following:

```
CAST(CAST(InvoiceDate as smalldatetime) as float) + 2
```

Comment: I don't know why someone is marking this answer down.  This is an accurate answer.  The SQL string is a standard way of converting dates to Excel-friendly dates.

Comment: Nobody explained such Excel behavior. The reason for it is the regional settings. Excel expects values according to OS's regional settings. It's related to dates as well as numbers with the decimal separator. Evidently Brenda uses French settings, but imported data in English.